# Is possibile to firewall an OpenVPN tunnel using openvpn settings?

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have to install an openVPN server in a windows environment for a specific HTTP service.

```
openVPN-server         <--->    openVPN-client
VPN-TUNNEL 10.8.0.1/24          VPN-TUNNEL 10.8.0.2/24
LAN 192.168.0.1/24              LAN 10.0.0.10/16
```

I would like to secure the server to not let any user surf its LAN network while accessing the VPN.
For example I'm scared that throught the VPN a client can access file shares or RDP in the other network.

In the example above:

- I want to let the client accessing HTTPS page to 10.8.0.1
- I want to deny any connection from client to any other server-LAN service like RDP, fileshare and so on

Is there any way to restrict the openVPN tunnel using openVPN settings without adding a dedicated sw or hw firewall to the server machine?